# What's the number of significant characters in VBScript identifiers?

Tags: vbscript, identifier

Coming from "good" old days where there were languages which such a limit, I am wondering:

**Is there such a limit to the number of significant characters in identifiers in VBScript?**

There used to be BASIC variants that limited the total number of characters to 8, or 16 (MSX computers, real old ROM basics). Then, Turbo Pascal (I think) and GW-BASIC (I believe) allowed arbitrarily long identifiers, but only the first 20 or so characters where significant, so `VERYLONGNAMEWITHASUFFIX1` and `VERYLONGNAMEWITHASUFFIX2` where considered to be the same identifier.

That´s anachronism we won´t find in today´s (ok, yesterday's, because it is not a current technology) VBScript, right?

I am not a big fan of very long identifiers, but I´m generating VBScript source code for immediate execution at runtime, and that one might fiddle around with long identifiers and must not be human-readable (considering the developer not being a normal human being).

Astoundingly, I failed to google this at bing, or google ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

Variable names follow the standard rules for naming anything in VBScript. A variable name:

```
Must begin with an alphabetic character.

Cannot contain an embedded period.

Must not exceed 255 characters.

Must be unique in the scope in which it is declared.
```

Comment: I am ashamed for reading an "rtfm" in between the lines, even if you did not intend that at all. Thanks.

Comment: @TheBlastOne As there is bit of luck involved in searching for specific info I didn't refer to the docs to chide you but to base my answer on evidence and to encourage others to make an n+1 attempt if the first n trials failed.

Comment: These docs are not very complete; `MyVar1` is valid, `MyVar#1` not while `[MyVar Number #01#]` is a valid variablename. The latter is usefull if you want to make references to functions that you want to use as dynamic pointers: Declaration of an add function: `Public Function [+](x, y)` and use it in a function reference: `MsgBox "The result is: " & GetRef(inputbox("What operation should I do on your numbers 18 and 24?"))(18, 24)`

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, yes I gotya

Comment: @AutomatedChaos wtf? While I´ve seen that elsewhere, I still don´t understand because where in the MsgBox line do you reference the [+] function?

Comment: @TheBlastOne well, in this demonstration the user is asked to enter that (the `+`) in the inputbox, then the `[+]` function is called by the reference and 18 and 24 are added resulting in a msgbox with 42. The point is, you can create a `function [+](x, y)` and refer to it with `GetRef("+")`. Or just call it with something like `MsgBox [+](3,4)`. It is nice if you are using a keyword driven test framework where you have keywords like `create user`. Now you can refer to the function `[create user]` by `Set objKeyword = GetRef(strKeyword)`.

Comment: How sick is that. Thanx :D